# Convert SQL Server query to DB2

Tags: sql-server, db2

In our applications database will be changed from SQL Server to db2.

Dba will take care about data migration. Is there any way or utility to input a SQL Server (T-SQL) query and output is the equivalent db2 query?

Utility will convert SQL Server query to db2 specific query, tried with google, but didn't find any comprehensive solution.

Till this what I found one need to put manual effort converting all queries.

Note : no hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You should look at  [IBM® Database Conversion Workbench plugin](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=05901c97-75b2-47a1-9c32-25f748855913) for IBM Data Studio.

An older product is the [IBM DB2 migration toolkit](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/product.jsp?id=GFAH-4ULUTN&cat=database)...